# Black borders around the window when taking a screenshot

Tags: virtualbox, 19.10, gnome-screenshot

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 on VirtualBox. When I take a screenshot of a window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>, there is a black border around the window.

[image: black border around window]

I didn't have this issue in previous versions of Ubuntu (19.04, 18.04). Is there any way to remove the border?

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed a new bug. As a workaround you can add "drop shadow" effect while taking screenshot from a window.

In command line you can use this:

```
gnome-screenshot -w --border-effect=shadow
```